# Create Microsoft Teams Channel calendar event with Default Channel details using graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I would like to know is there any graph api call, that can be utilized to create an event in the Microsoft Team's Channel Calendar?

Or if we can call an api where we can pass on the Channel details like :
ABC > General Channel to create an event?

Any help?

Comment: `create an event in the Microsoft Team's Channel Calendar`  --> this api? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: per my test before, when I use this api to create the meeting, it would appear in teams calendar. You can test this api in API explorer

Comment: Hello, it will not attach the event to the channel calendar

Comment: oh sorry I ignored the channel calendar, and I'm afraid it's not supported. I found a related question here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/657295/post-api-to-create-calender-events-for-teams-chann

Answer (score 0):

We tried using below API and meeting got created as below. Could you please try  in this way and let us know if it helps?

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/calendar/events

{
    "subject": "Group calendar meet",
    "body": {
        "contentType": "HTML",
        "content": "Does thie meet work for you?"
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2023-03-24T12:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2023-03-24T14:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "location": {
        "displayName": "PSD's Bar"
    },
    "attendees": [
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "address": "adelev@M365x654992.onmicrosoft.com",
                "name": "Adele Vance"
            },
            "type": "required"
        }
    ],
    "transactionId": "7E163156-7762-4BEB-A1C6-729EA81755A7"
}
```

Response:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Will it also be displayed in channel calendar?

Comment: In channel, the created meeting was not showing, but here in Outlook calendar it does show up.